# Google map with custom marker CSS animation

Tags: html, css, google-maps

How can add custom marker css animation into Google map ? before I ask about it but no one answer and just dislike my question, Finally I find answer and I want share it with other who need this trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/vujenuwifo

```js
function CustomMarker(latlng,  map) {
  this.latlng_ = latlng;

  // Once the LatLng and text are set, add the overlay to the map.  This will
  // trigger a call to panes_changed which should in turn call draw.
  this.setMap(map);
}

CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
  var me = this;

  // Check if the div has been created.
  var div = this.div_;
  if (!div) {
    // Create a overlay text DIV
    div = this.div_ = document.createElement('DIV');
    // Create the DIV representing our CustomMarker
    div.style.border = "none";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.paddingLeft = "0px";
    div.style.cursor = 'pointer';

    var dv = document.createElement("div");
    dv.className='pin bounce'
    div.appendChild(dv);

    var dvx= document.createElement("div");
    dvx.className='pulse'
    div.appendChild(dvx);
    ;

    // Then add the overlay to the DOM
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
  }

  // Position the overlay 
  var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
  if (point) {
    div.style.left = point.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = point.y + 'px';
  }
};


var map;
var overlay;
function initialize() {
  var opts = {
    zoom: 19,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.781481, 51.371445),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opts);

  overlay = new CustomMarker(map.getCenter(), map);

}
```

```css
.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #00cae9;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin:after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bounce {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
          animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
}

.pulse {
  background: #d6d4d4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(55deg);
          transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
          animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #00cae9;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
          animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
            transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
            transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 850px; height: 480px;">map div</div>
```